# removing last element created by ::after pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm creating a nav menu and I'm using the `::after` pseudo-element and I want to achieve this:

> home | about | articles | personal projects

This is my css code:

```
nav ul li::after{
    content: " | ";
}
```

This is my HTML markup:

```
<nav class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.php">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="/articles.php">articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/projects.php">personal projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Everything is good except for `::after` is adding a `|` at the very end (as expected)

ex:

> home | about | articles | personal projects |

Is there any way, only using css, to remove the last `|`?

I know I can use Javascript, or simply add this to my HTML. I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: You can use the last-child selector. Not sure if it works with psuedo elements, I will try and create a fiddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or, you can use a simple CSS2 piece of code :

```
nav ul li + li:before {
   content: " | ";
}
```

**And you won't have to worry about the last one**. Elegant, compatible.

*Sometimes, it's way more simple to use good old CSS selectors in the right way :)*

Answer (score 5):

A little long, but works:

```
nav ul li:last-child::after { content:''; }
```

or

```
nav ul li:last-child::after { display: none; }
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbZNXP)

Answer (score 3):

```
nav ul li:not(:last-child)::after{
  content: " | ";
}
```

> The **negation** CSS pseudo-class, **:not(X)**, is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector.
>
> The specificity of the **:not** pseudo-class is the specificity of its argument. The :not pseudo-class does not add to the selector
>   specificity, unlike other pseudo-classes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

In simple it will not add styles for the `:last-child`

Comment: Please explain a little what your CSS rule does.

Answer (score 1):

Yep

```
 nav ul li:last-child::after {
   content: "";
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/nz1j8rbw/)